# JNDI: what does it imply to have an empty hashtable in InitialContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, jndi

I get very common `java naming exception`, however, remarkably the `hashtable` is empty{}, what does it imply?

```
 javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hashtable {} [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:243)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:318)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:348)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:428)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
......
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:235)
... 16 more
```

The application is sitting on `Websphere 7` and JNDI with `v4` datasource the code is like this, nothing special

```
    InitialContext ctx = null;

    if(someCondition==true){
        ctx=new InitialContext();
    }

if( ctx != null ) {
    try {
        String jdbcDsName = getJdbcDSName();
        ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jdbcDsName);
    } catch ( NamingException ne) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you create or acquire `ctx?` And is there more of the stack trace? such as where the NPE was thrown from?

Comment: @EJP Thank you. I have updated the original post. Initially the ctx is null but when meets some condition it is initiated with InitialContext(), I turn on debug mode from Log4J the exception definitely come from `ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jdbcDsName);`

Comment: @EJP Weird thing is the ctx is not null, but it contains no content in the hashtable.

Comment: @EJP also add piece of exception in the original post.

Comment: What does "very common" mean (always, only in case of an invalid name, only at startup, ...). What's the type of the application (servlet, JSP, EJB, ...)? Are you using somewhere `NamingManager.setInitialContextFactoryBuilder`? Does `getInitialContextFactoryBuilder` always return a non-null value?